# How to use reduce to return a mapped object with arrays as values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of distinct objects. Some have the same `date` value. I'd like to group those with the same `date` together and return a mapped object where each `date` is the key and its value is an array of the object(s) with that same date. Here's the array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    date: '2/2/20',
    name: 'joe',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    date: '3/3/20',
    name: 'john',
    age: 67
  },
  {
    date: '2/2/20',
    name: 'chuck',
    age: 34
  },
  {
    date: '3/3/20',
    name: 'bob',
    age: 28
  },
  {
    date: '4/4/20',
    name: 'bill',
    age: 51
  }
]
```

I know something like this can be done with `map().filter()`, but it's not what I'm looking for, and plus I'm trying to do this with `reduce()` to save on resources.

So far I have:

```js
arr.reduce((acc, person) => {
  acc[person.date] = [ person ];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This only returns the last match, not all the matches:

```js
{
  '2/2/20': [ { date: '2/2/20', name: 'chuck', age: 34 } ],
  '3/3/20': [ { date: '3/3/20', name: 'bob', age: 28 } ],
  '4/4/20': [ { date: '4/4/20', name: 'bill', age: 51 } ]
}
```

I've tried other aspects of this solution but I can't seem to get it right. I also know how to get the mapped object that returns the count of the number of matches, but it's still not my solution:

```js
arr.reduce((acc, person) => {
  acc[person.date] = acc[person.date] + 1 || 1
  return acc
}, {})
```

This returns:

```js
{ '2/2/20': 2, '3/3/20': 2, '4/4/20': 1 }
```

So how can I use `reduce()` to get an object that contains all the matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize to an empty array if `acc[person.date]` doesn't exist, and `push` regardless:

```
arr.reduce((acc, person) => {
    acc[person.date] = (acc[person.date] || []);
    acc[person.date].push(person);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Destructuring one-line/spreading approach:

```
arr.reduce((acc, { date, ...o }) => ({ ...acc, [date]: [...(acc[date] || []), { date, ...o }), {});
```

Comment: The spread version doesn't work, it has a syntax error. I'd expect the spread approach to be very inefficient though due to creating multiple objects and arrays on each iteration rather than creating one array and pushing references from the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Jack Bashford's answer appears to be what you are looking for. I would just add that this is a very common operation often referred to as `groupBy`. This is implemented in most functional helper libraries (Lodash for example). You can also implement it yourself with something like:

```js
const groupBy = (cb, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((grouped, el) => {
    const key = cb(el)
    return {
      ...grouped,
      [key]: [...grouped[key] || [], el]
    }
  }, {})
```

(Note the above implementation is just an example and should not be considered a performant implementation. See [Lodash groupBy implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/groupBy.js).

and then for your use case:

```js
groupBy(el => el.date, arr)
```

which is helpful if you plan on doing similar operations.

Comment: Might update with `const res = groupBy(el => el.date, arr)` to show how to use the returned object

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the tip and helpful implementation!

Comment: Using spread means slightly less code, but in cases like these it's a very poor performer as it copies the accumulator and the object from the array (*el*) on every iteration.

Comment: @RobG I agree, it was just a hastily written example, but I suppose that's worth mentioning in the post.